# LibSVM unclear about usage

Tags: c++, libsvm

I have my own project where I intend to use LibSVM. I have read online that in order to use the library, all I need to do is to add svm.cpp and svm.h to my project. I have done that but I get a lot of redefinition errors on some of the objects in defined in the svm.cpp such as:

**"QMatrix": class redefintion**

After inspecting the code I see the classes declared in the cpp file.... I am used to have all my class definitions in the .h header files. I don't understand... Why is it like that? I also think that part of the reason I get redefinition errors is because of the declaration.

I know libSVN is a very popular library. Could someone please explain why are all the classes are in .cpp file? And how do I compile these files so I could use them?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't `#include` any .cpp files.

Comment: @KerrekSB Do not include any .cpp file in what file? svm.cpp? I only added my `#include "stdafx.h"` to svm.cpp